# Tornado Bidirectional communication without websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, tornado

I'm building a Tornado based server that basically allows the user to upload an image, does some processing on the backend and returns some updates during and after the processing.

I've implemented a basic server using Handlers, which works nicely.
The problem is that the handler interface doesn't allow me to communicate with the client, but only to re-render the entire page.

I've considered using WebSockets, but from what I see they shouldn't be used for image uploading, so it kind of kills this option.

Is there any other way to communicate with a specific client from an Handler (i.e render only part of the page, trigger some js event and so on).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using POST and GET methods in your handlers?

If you're using a GET method to receive the image from your client, you can communicate with the client by returning data using the self.write(json_data) method. (http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/structure.html) However, once the GET method returns the request is considered to be finished, so you might not be able to send multiple updates.

Also, can you also configure the client side? I'm assuming you're using a JSON GET method to make a call to the tornado server, and in that case you can just link certain responses to different js functions in the client-side code.

Comment: Hi Ashely, I'm using a POST method due to the fact that I'm uploading an image when starting the handler. Can the self.write be used to trigger js functions in a POST method?

Comment: Yes, if you go here: (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) the server can return data in the 'success' variable.

Comment: I actually use the return data, the thing it allows me to only send one response and what I'm looking for is actual communication.

Comment: In that case, all I can suggest is having the server POST to the client.